# Can different shared memory be declared for different blocks in the same grid?

Tags: cuda, gpgpu, gpu

I already have asked this question [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24056996/is-variable-shared-memory-declaration-in-cuda-kernel-allowed) but didn't get any satisfactory answer. Maybe because I included multiple questions in that one.
My question is whether I am allowed to declare different shared memory for different blocks of the same grid or not.

Eg:

```
Dx = blockDim.x;
Dy = blockDim.y;
Bx = BlockIdx.x;
By = BlockIdx.y;

if(By==0)
 {
  if (Bx==0)
  {
   __shared__ bds[5][5];
  }
  else if (Bx==(Dy-1))
  {
   __shared__ bds[6][6];
  }
  else
  {
   __shared__ bds[5][6];
  }
}
```

Above code is the part of a kernel code. I am trying to allocate specific amount of shared memory to specific blocks. Is this kind of behavior allowed in CUDA?

Comment: Why do you say that you didn't receive an answer? You are trying to statically allocate shared memory with size known at runtime. This was pointed out in the comment to your previous post.

Comment: I think that the answer to your question is NO. To change the size of the shared memory the way you are trying you should be able to discriminate the block ID at run-time.

Comment: #JackOLantern: My question was not regarding the dynamic memory allocation of any compile error due to __shared__ bds[Dy+1][Dx+2]

Comment: No, _it was_. But now you have edited it...

Comment: #JackOLantern: My question is not regarding the dynamic memory allocation error or any compile error due to bds[Dy+1][Dx+2] or anything like that. It wasn't answered in my last question. Though I have edited my question.

Comment: #JackOLantern: Let me put it this way for you:
If Block 0 --> Then __shared__ bds[5][5]
If Block 1 --> Then __shared__ bds[5][6]
If Block 2 --> Then __shared__ bds[6][6]

Or Like this:
If Block number = Even --> Then __shared__ bds[6][6]
If Block number = Odd  --> Then __shared__ bds[5][5]

Now these are just examples so please don't relate to any errors and all. My question is whether this kind of behavior allowed in CUDA i.e. variable sized share memory allocation for different blocks.

Comment: #JackOLatern: You are wrong, and answer of my question is YES! I can declare different variable size shared memory for different blocks in the same grid. I successfully implemented a program with 16 (4*4) blocks. I declared 9 different types of shared memories over my 16 blocks.

Comment: It is a bit hypocrite to post a question in which the code was _exactly_ equal to the previous post, receive a comment accordingly, editing the post and claiming that the previous comment was wrong.

Comment: @sandeep.ganage: Did you look at the amount of shared memory statically reserved by the compiler for that kernel? Did you notice that it is *the sum of all nine static allocations*?

Comment: JackOLatern: Yeah, in previous one I asked three questions..Out of which I got answers for two. For the unanswered question I posted this question, and of course with the same code! Funny part is getting same repeated irrelevant answers again and again.

Comment: JackOLatern: More funny rather suspicious part is somebody is getting UP for his every comment. Even for this "No, it was. But now you have edited it... ".

Comment: @talonmies I had this suspect since the OP's edit, but had no possibility to verify it. Conceptually, a static allocation cannot depend on runtime values and the compiler is just considering a worst-case scenario. I think you should post a definite answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now that the target has stopped swinging around and there is a concrete, stable question to answer:

Yes, it is perfectly possible to do this but note that

1. Each statically defined shared memory variable has restricted scope within the kernel that will make code structure much more complex than it needs to be
2. The compiler will emit a separate static shared memory reservation for each variable you define in shared memory. If, as you say, you had a kernel with 9 conditionally defined, local scoped shared memory allocations, the kernel will be compiled with a static reservation which is the *sum of the statically defined size of all nine variables*.
3. Point 2 implies that even though you have different conditionally declared allocations of shared memory, the amount of shared memory per block *is the same*

Points two and three means that there are no size efficiency gains to be had by the scheme you propose. Quite the opposite, in fact. Your kernel will need much more shared memory than if you just had a single statically declared shared memory which was the largest each case required and you coded accordingly.